# Issue with ScrollView setcontentoffset

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am adding pages (views) to scroll view while the view is offscreen like this

```
-(void)loadScrollView:(NSInteger)CurrentPage
{
    int pageNo=objGameData.CurrentPageNo-1;
    [self.EDDescriptionScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((pageNo*EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width)+80, EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.height)];

    self.EDDescriptionScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width*objGameData.CurrentPageNo,EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.height);




    edView=[[EDView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((CurrentPage-1)*EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width, EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.height)];

    [edView.EDMsgTextView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.EDDescrptionArray objectAtIndex:(CurrentPage-1)]]];
    edView.EDMsgTextView.delegate=self;
    edView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    edView.CorrectWordLbl.text=self.CurrentWord;
    edView.TotalPointsLost.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points : %d",objGameData.CurrentPointsLostEarned];
    edView.tag=pageNo;
    [self.EDDescriptionScrollView addSubview:edView];
}
```

Now when I move the super view of EDDescriptionScrollView on screen and want to jump to some page other than the last one added , I simply do

```
 [self.EDDescriptionScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((pageNo*EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width)+80, EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

It is taking the scroll view to the page but the content only show up when I touch the screen.
Anything I am doing which is wrong?
I have tried calling layoutsubview as well, problem persists.

Comment: why don't you use method scrollRectToVisible:animated:?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[self.EDDescriptionScrollView layoutIfNeeded]`

Answer (score 0):

`[self.EDDescriptionScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((pageNo*EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.width)+80, EDDescriptionScrollView.frame.size.height)];` 
the "pageNo" should be "pageNo - 1"